backgroundImage on button not showing
I am trying to set a background image on a button I have, but it seems to be not working.
Versions used:

Next.js - 14.2.6
Tailwindcss - 3.4.1

Here is my problem:
      <button
        onClick={() => console.log('mobile menu clicked')}
        className="right-4 top-4 z-50 h-10 w-10 bg-menu-burger"
      ></button>

and here is part of my tailiwind.config.ts file where I set the background image:
      backgroundImage: {
        'menu-close': 'url("/images/menu-close.svg")',
        'menu-burger': url("/images/menu-burger.svg")',
      }

The images are located in the public directory in the images sub-directory. But still the background image does not display on the screen. But when I inspect the page, I can see the background image property is being set, and also the image is being loaded, but the image is not visible on the screen.
I have read on a reddit post that when setting a background image it looks relative to the index.css file (in Next.js case globals.css) file. So I have tried to do that:
      backgroundImage: {
        'menu-close': 'url("../../public/images/menu-close.svg")',
        'menu-burger': "url('../../public/images/menu-burger.svg')",
      }

Still the image is not being shown on the screen, but as always the background image property is being set on the button and the image is loaded on the browser when I manually click on it from the developer tools. But the interesting thing in this approach was that the path of the image changed, instead of /images/menu-burger.svg to /_next/static/media/menu-burger.07dc2524.svg.
My understanding so far is that it has something to do with how Next.js handles static files. Any help or suggestion would be great!!
UPDATE: When I use the image with an img tag, it works the image is visible in the screen.

Is your image "match" the button shape? Maybe you should try to center it?
